# Rendering an isometric map in java with individual rectangles

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, isometric

I've been researching for the past hour or so and I can't seem to render an isometric map. I want to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx4cg.png).
But I am getting [this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0SqQ.png). I am storing my map as tiles in a 1 dimensional array like so:

```
private final int width, height;
    private final int tileWidth, length;
    private int[] tiles;

    public Level(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        tiles = new int[width * height];
        tileWidth = 68;
        length = 48;
    }
```

I am passing through 10, 10 as the parameters for width and height. And I render the map like so:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    g.drawRect(x * tileWidth, y * length / 2, tileWidth, length);
                else
                    g.fillRect((x * tileWidth) + (tileWidth / 2), (y * length / 2), width, length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I've wanted to learn to make isometric games but have been stuck with flat 2D for a while.

Answer (score 1):

For just tiles, you could use a [shear transform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getShearInstance%28double,%20double%29):

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getShearInstance(1, 0);
g2d.transform(at);
// rest of your drawing code here
```

You may also want to set the shear anchor point:

```
double sa_x = 100, sa_y = 100; // or whatever
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

// S3: Move back to original origin
at.translate(sa_x, sa_y);

// S2: Shear
at.shear(1, 0);

// S1: Set origin
at.translate(-sa_x, -sa_y);
```

You can vary the shear factor `1` to get different amounts of shear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing rects, you need to draw lines at isometric angles.

The angles in isometric geometry are 30 degrees, 90 degrees, 150 degrees, 210 degrees and 270 degrees (in radians: pi/6, pi/2, 5pi/6, 7pi/6, 3pi/2, 11pi/6.).

cos(pi/6) is sqrt(3)/2 or 0.866... and sin(pi/6) is 1/2 or 0.5. (This is meaningful because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sin-cos-defn-I.png )

This means that if you want to draw a line at the angle pi/6 that is D pixels long starting at x1,y1:

```
x2 = x1+cos(pi/6)*D e.g. x1+D*sqrt(3)/2
y2 = y1+sin(pi/6)*D e.g. y1+D/2
```

and draw from x1,y1 to x2,y2.

All the other angles are either reflections of this (one dimension or both are made negative) or straight up and down (trivial to draw).

To calculate **where** on the screen to draw an isometric object, consider that isometric geometry has three dimensions: X, Y, Z. Movement by Z will just make you draw D higher or D lower. Movement by X or Y will move you in one isometric angled direction or the other, by the same x and y as the distance of drawing one tile line in that direction (so similar formula to the above).